# Fade in image on page load

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

How would I fade in an image on page load using Angular JS, currently this is my code on AngularJS, but it doesn't work (based off of: http://plnkr.co/edit/ncqEB3PafIWbwv0UH1QG?p=preview)

**View**

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/logo-blue.svg" class="navbar-logo" ng-class="{'fade-in': vm.fade }"></object>
```

**Controller**

```
vm.fade = true;
```

**CSS**

```
.animation { opacity:0; transition:all 200ms ease-in-out; }

.animation.fade-in { opacity:1; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the class="animation" to the object element

Comment: Yes, https://plnkr.co/edit/O09qHjSWzIHgJa60gvuo have you set the ng-controller with the alias vm?

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add animate class on you object tag

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/logo-blue.svg" class="animation navbar-logo" ng-class="{'fade-in': vm.fade }"></object>`

Comment: in css your animation duration is .2s == 200ms. make it larger so you can see the difference

Comment: Ok so I have changed it to `.animation { opacity:0; transition:all 5s ease-in-out; }` but it still doesn't work

Comment: on your give plunker example in added <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" class="animation" ng-class="{'fade-in': fade }"></object> and it was working fine

Answer (score 0):

I did it with one line of javascript and one css style.

This went right before the element that I wanted to fade in:

```
<div id = 'fadewrap' >    
<script>
document.getElementById("fadewrap").style.opacity = 1;                      
</script>


#fadewrap {
    opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all 1.75s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 1.75s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 1.75s ease;
   -o-transition: all 1.75s ease;
    transition: all 1.75s ease;     
}
```